# MongoDB select all fields that have values that are not in an array

Tags: mongodb, search

I have the following scenario:

```
 { 
   id: 1,
   field_X: [a, b]
 },
 { 
   id: 2,
   field_X: [c, d]
 },
 { 
   id: 3,
   field_X: [d]
 },
 { 
   id: 4,
   field_X: [a]
 },
 { 
   id: 5,
   field_X: [a,b,c,f]
 }
```

I want to find all fields that have any element from this array:
    [a, b, c]
but do not have any other element; so the correct result will be:

```
 { 
   id: 1,
   field_X: [a, b]
 },
 { 
   id: 4,
   field_X: [a]
 }
```

How can I do this in MongoDB?

Answer (score 3):

```
db.collection.find({ 'field_X': {'$in': [/[abc]/], '$nin': [/[^abc]/]} })
```

Comment: now, do you have any idea how can I move this into PHP?

Comment: @ClaudiuHardalau [Chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions/) are not encouraged on SO as it looks like your original problem _How can I do this in MongoDB?_ is solved, isn't it?

Comment: so, basically you are suggesting this: db.getCollection('users').find({ 'role_id': {'$in': [/['a', 'b', 'c']/], '$nin': [/[^'a', 'b', 'c']/]} }) ? it does not seems to work correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
db_name.collection_name.find(({'field_X': {'$in': ['a', 'b', 'c'], '$nin': ['d', 'f']} })
```

Comment: The thing is that b and f are unknown and can be variable.